# Aero Snap broken when setting Window.owner

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like a child window that stays on top of the main window but not windows from other programs. And for the child window to minimize/restore with the main window. Setting the child window's `owner` property to the main window does this, but now the child's Aero Snap position is lost when the main window is minimized and then restored. Any idea how to fix that, while maintaining the previous behaviors?

Demo:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        var newWindow = new Window()
        {
            Title = "child window",
            Height = 200,
            Width = 300,
            Owner = this,
        };
        newWindow.Show();
    };
}
```